# Android BluetoothSocket not closing

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

I have a strange issue that I can't seem to figure out what's going on.
I am using the Bluetooth chat example as a base and things work fine for the most part, however, when trying to swtich connections from one UUID to another (two different apps). The hardware closes the connection and opens a new one with the different UUID.

The problem is that my bluetooth socket isn't getting closed on the app side. I see these messages in the log:

```
11-20 15:00:44.287: I/BTL_IFC(13313): btl_ifc_ctrl_rx: [BTL_IFC CTRL] recv BTLIF_BTS_RFC_DISC_IND (BTS) 11 pbytes (hdl 47)
11-20 15:00:44.287: I/BLZ20_WRAPPER(13313): btlif_ctrl_callback: btlif_ctrl_callback : msg id BTLIF_BTS_RFC_DISC_IND
11-20 15:00:44.287: I/BLZ20_WRAPPER(13313): btlif_process_disc_ind: disconnect ind status 19, rc chan 8
11-20 15:00:44.287: D/BLZ20_WRAPPER(13313): btlif_signal_event:  fd (-1:51), bta 5, rc 8, wflags 0x0, cflags 0x6, port 9053
11-20 15:00:44.287: D/BLZ20_WRAPPER(13313): btlif_signal_event: ### event BTLIF_BTS_RFC_DISC_IND not matched ###
11-20 15:00:44.287: I/BTL_IFC(13313): send_ctrl_msg: [BTL_IFC CTRL] send BTLIF_BTS_RFC_DISC_IND_ACK (BTS) 9 pbytes (hdl 47)
```

So I know it's being disconected, however my socket remains open. I would assume when I try to do this it would give me anI/O exception, but it doesnt.

```
mmInStream.available()
```

It just returns 0 and keeps going. I also monitored the mClosed flag in the BluetoothSocket.java class and it never gets set to true in this case.

I'm registered for the the normal dissconnect intents, am I missing one?

```
    IntentFilter stateChangeFilter = new IntentFilter("android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED");
    IntentFilter disconnectFilter1 = new IntentFilter("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED");
    IntentFilter disconnectFilter2 = new IntentFilter("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED");

    registerReceiver(mListenForDisconnect,stateChangeFilter );
    registerReceiver(mListenForDisconnect,disconnectFilter1 );
    registerReceiver(mListenForDisconnect,disconnectFilter2 );
```

Comment: The only thing that can cause it to crash is if I try to do `mmOutStream.write(byte)` but I don't want to just write bytes out constantly to see if there's still a connection.